# How to build C interpreter using C++ or some other PL

Tags: c++, c, interpreter

I am looking at creating an interpreter for the C language.

I have got hold of this [link](http://www.drdobbs.com/184408184) but I would like to know if there is any better way to do it. Right now, I am looking at implementing it using C++. But if there is any other language which is better at this task then I am willing to change to that for this purpose .

I am building the interpreter for static analysis purpose, which would require operations like statement labeling, address storing, Heap address storing and other operations typically required for this analysis.

Any links which would help me in getting started would be great. Please share your thoughts and I would really appreciate it since it is a completely new area for me. Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tool to statically analyze some code is not an interpreter.

Anyway, writing such tool is not a trivial thing, it requires a good understanding of how compilers work. Usually such job is split in many tasks: tokenizing the code, parsing it and building an abstract syntax tree first of all

These operations are simple to do once you declare your language (in this case C) rules, and there are many tools to automatize the process. Most famous tool is probably bison (which is for C); there are also many really good and easy-to-use C++ libraries (like boost.spirit), and even some languages which have been designed in order to do these stuff.

My suggestion is thus to improve your knowledge about compilers, and to try and write some parsers for simpler languages. You cannot start analyzing C from nowhere.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am trying to do pointer analysis and So I have to stick with C . Not that I am unaware of C or C++, but I am not sure of how to proceed with this task. 

The tasks like tokenizing, parsing are all the part of compiling. So you mean to say that , it will be more like a Compiler ?

Comment: Yes, an interpreter or a static analyzer share A LOT of things with a compiler. Only few _high-level modules_ are different. About C++, I was suggesting to use C++ libraries to do your job, thus to write your tool in C++; the result will of course parse C only (if you use C rules to define your tool). Parsing C++, by the way, is A HELL compared to parsing C.

Comment: Could you elaborate more where things get different ? i.e. in context with this approach ? Is there any particular resource to start with ? I have googling for a very long time but I could not get a proper hit to start with !!! By the way, I too was mentioning about C++ just as a implementor only. Parsing C++, that will one of a hell of a job ,like you mentioned !

Comment: For a static analysis you'd need to take a look at the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest using a library to do the parsing ?

Clang is a modular project providing (amongst other things) a C parser that yields a AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) that you can freely explore.

It also has a Static Analyzer work in progress, led by Ted Kremenek, that you should perhaps check out... and maybe you'll be able to contribute to it :)

Comment: Clang has also been one of the things which I have been looking at. Since I am not yet aware of the magnitude of the work which is ahead of me ( Guess, I now know that it is monsterous !), I am trying to find all the options available and take the one which would also help me getting knowledgeable.

Answer (score 1):

Clang was already mentioned, so for the "other PL" part of the question I'd suggest to take a look at http://cil.sourceforge.net/